# How to add users to AuthenticationManagerBuilder from a file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am writing a Google Chrome extension that requires user authentication that I have set up with Spring, and currently I have a few example usernames and passwords in my code while I'm still developing. At this point, I am ready to add real usernames and passwords, but I want to be able to load them into an `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` object from an outside file.

Here is the relevant code so far:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()   
            .withUser("user1").password("password1").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("user2").password("password2").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("user3").password("password3").roles("USER");
}
```

I want to be able to build the `auth` object instead from a file that would contain something like this:

```
user1    password1
user2    password2
user3    password3
```

How would I do this (if it is even possible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) instead. Just read the file inside the `loadUserByUsername(String username)` method, if any user with the given `username` exists, return a [`UserDetails`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) or [`User`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) representing that user. Otherwise throw a [`UsernameNotFoundException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UsernameNotFoundException.html) exception:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // Read the file
    // Loop through all users and search for the given username
    // Return User or throw UsernameNotFoundException
    auth.userDetailsService(username -> {
            try {
                String pathToFile = // Path to file;
                List<String> users = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(pathToFile));
                for (String user : users) {
                    String[] parts = user.split("\\s+", 2);
                    String theUsername = parts[0];
                    String password = parts[1];

                    if (username.equals(theUsername))
                        return new User(theUsername, password, Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")));
                }
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username");
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to expand this code a bit more? Thanks @ali-dehghani

Comment: given the `split` call, is there any particular way my user/password file should be formatted? As in, user *space* password or user *tab* password?

Comment: `\\s+` means at least one `space`, which covers both mentioned scenarios

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler way:

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer imudmc = auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
        String[] creds = {"user|password", "user2|password"};
        for (int i = 0; i < creds.length; i++) {
            imudmc.withUser(StringUtils.substringBefore(creds[i], "|")).password(StringUtils.substringAfter(creds[i], "|")).roles("USER");
        }
    }
```

Obviously the array should be read in from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Define in JSON including roles. Tested from String rather file using own serialiser (supports JSON and XML).

```
        consumers = (Consumers) serialiser.recover("{ \"Consumers\" : [ { \"Name\" : \"localhost\", \"Password\" : \"none\", \"Roles\" : [ \"USER\", \"ADMIN\" ]  } ]}", Consumers.class);
        if (null != consumers && null != consumers.getConsumers()) {
            InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer imudmc = auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
            for (Consumer consumer : consumers.getConsumers()) {
                   imudmc.withUser(consumer.getName()).password(consumer.getPassword()).roles(consumer.getRoles());
            }
        }
```